# Do all spectrums have a drum?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Assume we have a set of eigenvalues $$0 < \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \ldots \lambda_n \to \infty,$$ where the only rules I impose are that they are positive and have no limit point.

Does there exists a drum $$D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$ such that the Laplacian has this set of eigenvalues as its spectrum?

Comment: This may be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum#Weyl.27s_formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by whpowell96, Weyl's law states that

$$
A = 4 \pi \lim_{R \to \infty} \dfrac{N(R)}{R}
$$

where $A$ is the area of the drum and $N(R)$ is the number of eigenvalues less than $R$.

We can find counterexamples by looking at sequences of eigenvalues that would imply $A = 0$ or $A = \infty$.

For example, the sequence of eigenvalues $\lambda_n = 2^n$ would have no drum since $N(R) \le \log_2 (R)$ and

$$
A = 4 \pi \lim_{R \to \infty} \dfrac{N(R)}{R} \le 4 \pi \lim_{R \to \infty} \dfrac{ \log_2(R)}{R} = 0$$

Comment: What is the condition for a drum to exist? That $A$ be finite and non-zero?

Comment: ... and more counterexamples where the limit does not exist.

Comment: @StefanLafon No, there are other requirements too.  For example (see Kac's article [Can One Hear the Shape of a Drum?](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/MarkKac.pdf)) $$\sum_n \exp(-t \lambda_n) \sim\frac{A}{2\pi t} - \frac{L}{4 \sqrt{2\pi t}} \ \text{as}\ t \to 0+$$ 
where $L$ is the perimeter of the drum, and the isoperimetric inequality says $L^2 \ge 4\pi A$ with equality only for a circle.  So if $L$ is too small, there is no drum.